# Basic autofit feature impossible with DevExpress GridControl.View

Tags: grid, devexpress, width

I have a DevExpress grid like this:

```
        <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding CarsData}" 
                         AutoPopulateColumns="True"
                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView Style="{StaticResource DxTableViewStyle}"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Car Name"  FieldName="CarName" ReadOnly="False" />
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Brand Name" FieldName="BrandName" ReadOnly="True"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
```

This grid is embeded into another container with a **Fixed Width**.

I would like to do something simpel but can't find how to do this, i.e.:

- Have the **columns autofit** their content and headers.
- If the columns get wider than the container of the grid, **display a horizontal scroll bar**
- For some columns, set a max width.

Here is my style that I can't get working like I want:

```
<Style TargetType="dxg:TableView" x:Key="DxTableViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="AllowBestFit" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="BestFitArea" Value="All"/>
    <Setter Property="BestFitMode" Value="VisibleRows"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoWidth" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollbarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
</Style>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Call the method "BestFitColumns" on the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Sebi said in his comment, you should call the `BestFitColumns` on the `GridView`. I used to do it but now I avoid using it because it slows soooo much the loading of the grid, especially if you have an important set of data to show (it iterates through all the rows to find the best width for each column).

I recommend you to manually set the width of each column (the user can adjust the visible width if he wants to).

EDIT : Of course, if the total width of the `GridView` is larger than the `GridControl`'s width, an horizontal scroll-bar will be automatically set to the veiw.

Comment: Hi. Sorry but don't get it. I don't have any GridView in my XAML so don't know where to put this. thanks

Comment: I don;t have a single line of code behind so far so would like to keep it that way. Also surprised that a simple ptorperty setting cannot be done in the Xaml?